# How does appending names to many __init__*.py work?

Tags: python, init

I'm analyzing python code with two init-like files in it. The names are `__init__solvers.py` and `__init__cases.py` and they contain typical `__init__.py` structure and initialization data. For example, `__init__solvers.py` contains the following:

```
# List of solvers
solvers = ["s1", "s2", "s3"]

# Wrapper for solvers
def Solver(choice, options):
    "Return solver instance for given choice"
    exec("from %s import Solver as ChosenSolver" % choice)
    return ChosenSolver(options)
```

The main module imports solvers and Solver as such:

```
from solvers import Solver, solvers
```

A similar approach is done for the contents of `__init__cases.py`. It is written for Python 2.x. The directory structure looks like this:

```
main/
  __init__.py
  mainmodule.py
  solversandcases/
    __init__solvers.py
    __init__cases.py
    basicsolver.py # where BasicSolver() class is defined
    basiccase.py # where BasicCase() class is defined
    s1.py # where Solver(BasicSolver) class is defined
    c1.py # where Case(BasicCase) class is defined
```

The code executes with the following command:

```
python2 mainmodule.py s1 c1
```

where s1 is the choice of solver and 'c1' the choice of case to run. Runs without exceptions and produces the expected output. I just have no clue how this actually works and there is nothing in the official documentation about appending names to `__init__.py` file names. Can anybody explain it?

Comment: Is there also an `__init__.py`?

Comment: Yes, in all folders except the one with the 2 `__init__*.py`.

Comment: Can you post a minimal directory/file structure that replicates this functionality? I'm not able to get this to run after creating `main/__init__.py` and `main/solvers/__init__solvers.py` and running with `python2 -m main`.

Comment: @Blender added the directory structure. As is the code runs with the server python2 install. I'm wondering if it's not a lower level hack to the python2 installation on the server because there is absolutely nothing in the code that handles it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example .  You still need to show the contents of the `__init__.py` file and the details about how you're executing the code.

Comment: BTW, there is no magic "appending names / many `__init__`" feature for Python. This just looks like plain old bad packaging, the presence of an exec'ed import statement gives it all away.

Comment: @wim The entire code is too large to post. I posted what I can manage from the package. As for "magic appendages to `__init__.py`", I realize there is no such thing in the official python releases. Yet the code works and I have no idea why. This is what makes me wonder about a custom python install. I also don't see the point of bundling both Solver and Case classes in the same directory. One can just create separate directories and revert to a conventional  `__init__.py`. I already posted the contents of `__init__solvers.py`. The other `__init__.py` don't have anything related.

Comment: @wim I agree about the bad packaging, but the question is about the possibility of using an unconventional name for `__init__.py`.

Comment: Well, nobody can explain it without seeing the contents of `mainmodule.py`.  Voting to close as off-topic because non-reproducible.